# How can I have a "Universal" id system in prisma that returns a typed object?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

Let's say I have two database tables one for `images` and one for `videos`, they both have cuid primary keys, and I want to do a find with a key for instance "cld7q83rc000008mfc3pq5q6a" that could be an image or it could be a video how do I set my database up in this way?

It seems I have a couple of options:

1. A "universal key" table that is non-relational? id, table_name, item_id
2. A "universal key" table that is relational? id, image_id, video_id, ...etc
3. A VIEW that somehow generates this table dynamically?
4. A joined query with all tables

I'm interested in maintain type information

```
function findAny (cuid: string) {
  const universal = await prisma.universal.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: 'cld7q83rc000008mfc3pq5q6a',
    },
  })

  if (universal.image) {
     return {...universal.image, extraImageInfo: true }
  } else {
     return getTypeFromUniversalFind(universal)
  }
}
```

Update:

Option 1:

```
model Image {
  uuid String @db.Uuid @default(uuid()) @unique
  src String
}

model Video {
  uuid String @db.Uuid @default(uuid()) @unique
  src String
}

model UniversalKey {
  uuid String @db.Uuid @default(uuid()) @unique
  table String # "image" or "video"
  itemUuid String # not an actual relation
}
```

Option 2:

```
model Image {
  uuid String @db.Uuid @default(uuid()) @unique
  src String
  universalKey UniversalKey?
}

model Video {
  uuid String @db.Uuid @default(uuid()) @unique
  src String
  universalKey UniversalKey?
}

model UniversalKey {
  uuid String @db.Uuid @default(uuid()) @unique
  image Image? @relation(fields: [imageId], references: [uuid])
  imageId String? @unique
  video Video? @relation(fields: [videoId], references: [uuid])
  videoId String? @unique
  # ... you have to update this for every new type
}
```

Comment: Re 1 & 2: why would you have separate `id` and `item_id`? Also why do you call this "non-relational"? Re 3: don't put "view" in quotes. You literally want to create a `VIEW`. Re 4: not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: And then there's approach 5: just put the item kind in one of the bits of the cuid (if you're ok with "leaking" that information).

Comment: This is related "Feed with multiple types - Interfaces/Unions workaround" https://v1.prisma.io/forum/t/feed-with-multiple-types-interfaces-unions-workaround/2450/5

Comment: @Bergi Updated to show difference between 1 and 2, 4 is not having a UniversalKey table and running a custom query to search Item and Video at the same time via a JOIN.

Comment: Support for a Union type #2505 -> https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2505